# Example of linear functional from Rudin's book

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

Rudin states that $\Lambda(f)=\int \limits_{X}fg d\mu$ is linear functional. We know that $\exists M$ such that $|g|\leqslant M$. Hence $|fg|\leqslant M|f|$ $\Rightarrow$ $\int \limits_{X}|fg|d\mu<\infty$ and $fg$ is measurable $\Rightarrow$ $fg\in L^1(\mu)$. So $\Lambda(\alpha f_1+\beta f_2)=\alpha \Lambda(f_1)+\beta \Lambda(f_2)$ is obvious since $fg\in L^1(\mu)$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes: you are right.

Comment: @Crostul, Thanks a lot for checking!